# Invalid Hook call. Hooks can only be called in the body of a functional component react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am getting this error even though I am calling hooks correctly, this is my flatlist.
Basically I am trying to set a state when user taps on a text. But whenever I try to navigate to the screen with this flatlist I am getting the Invalid hooks error. I am following the hooks rules as far as I can understand.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            style={styles.flatList}
            data={interestGroupSampleData}
            renderItem={InterestGroupPostItem}
            ListHeaderComponent={headerComponent}

        />


    </View>
```

Below is the code for the InterestGroupPostItem

```
     const InterestGroupPostItem=({item}) => {
    const [isDetailsVisible,setDetailsVisible] = useState(false)
return (
        <View style={styles.flatListItemContainer}>
<TouchableOpacity
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                onPress={viewMorePress}>
                <View style={{ marginBottom: 5,paddingLeft: width * 0.02, }}>
                    <Text style={[styles.descriptionText]} numberOfLines={isDetailsVisible ? 0 : 2}>
                        {item.description}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={[styles.seeMoreText]}>{isDetailsVisible ? 'See Less' : 'more'}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Later I found that this was the issue in my code, I am not sure why this was throwing the error in the fist place, but the below code for the flatlist render item solved my issue.

```
<FlatList
                style={styles.flatList}
                data={interestGroupSampleData}
                renderItem={(props)=> <InterestGroupPostItem {...props}/>}
                ListHeaderComponent={headerComponent}

            />
```